# Android is not creating bitmap image from view

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am working on an android app and I am trying to create bitmap image from view. My view creation codes are,

```
private View createInflatedViewFromLayout(Context context, String question, String answer, ViewGroup containerView){

        View view;

        //Creating view from layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_export_view, (ViewGroup) containerView.getParent(), false);

        //Getting layout and text views
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.imageExportLayout);

        TextView pre_text_one = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout_pre_text_one);
        TextView pre_text_two = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout_pre_text_two);
        TextView pre_text_three = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout_pre_text_three);

        TextView post_text_one = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout_post_text_one);
        TextView post_text_two = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLayout_post_text_two);

        //Setting up typeface
        pre_text_one.setTypeface(custFont);
        pre_text_two.setTypeface(custFont);
        pre_text_three.setTypeface(custFont);

        post_text_one.setTypeface(custFont);
        post_text_two.setTypeface(custFont);


        //Setting up text and answer in text views
        post_text_one.setText(question);
        post_text_two.setText(answer);

        //To get random number so we can get color from colors array
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 0;
        int High = 5;
        int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors[Result][0]));
        post_text_one.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors[Result][1]));
        post_text_two.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors[Result][1]));


        return view;
    }
```

So this function is working properly and creating view. I have verified it by codes below,

```
final LinearLayout testLo = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.test_lo);

if(testLo.getChildCount() > 0)
                        testLo.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                    View lv = createInflatedViewFromLayout(context,
                            questions[(Integer)v.getTag()],
                            answers[(Integer)v.getTag()],
                            finalConvertView);

                    testLo.addView(lv, 0);
```

My bitmap image creation function is

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, Context ctx) {

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

and when I check the image with these codes,

```
Bitmap bmp = loadBitmapFromView(testLo.findViewById(0), context);
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
testLo.addView(image);
```

All I get is colored background but no text from view. And problem I am facing with with bitmap creation function is that I have to give height and width manually.

I mean if I use these codes,

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
```

or these codes,

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
```

it is crashing app by throwing error that height and width needs to be greater than 0. It is returning -1, -2 etc.

To create bitmap image I have also used below line of code,

```
Bitmap bmp = loadBitmapFromView(lv, context);
```

Can anyone tell me where I have problem? What do I need to change to get height, width and create image from layout view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I used this boilerplate code for creating bitmaps from my screen - in other words the code below will actually take a screenshot of your phone:

```
 final View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
 v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
 v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

If you only want to take a bitmap of a specific view, like a TextView or ImageView, you can just do this:

```
 TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);
 v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
 v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I will try this one but I don't want to take screenshot of it because view will be generated in background with details. It will not be shown.

Comment: That's fine. Then instead of using the first example, use the second example I gave u and set it to the view you want to make a bitmap of.

Comment: its not working, same issue. It is returning blank image with background colored only. and same problem with height and width.